# Android Studio: Calling a method In a Thread from the Main Activity

Tags: android, multithreading

I want to call the pauseThread method in the below code from the Main Activity
to stop the currentscore integer from counting. Some example code will be appreciated. If thats not possible, is their a way to stop counting on a button click? Perhaps pausing the thread?

```
public class ScoreThread extends Thread {

private boolean counter;
private int currentscore;
Handler scorehandler = new Handler();
private TextView playerscore;

 ScoreThread(TextView v, Boolean b) {
    playerscore = v;
    counter = b;
}

public void pauseThread() throws InterruptedException {
    counter = false;
}

public void resumeThread() throws InterruptedException {
    counter = true;
}


public void run() {
    currentscore = 0;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(counter == true) {
                currentscore = currentscore + 1;

                scorehandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        playerscore.setText("" + currentscore);
                    }
                });
                try{ Thread.sleep(50);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
}
```

Comment: First while(counter) should be enough instead of while(counter==true)

Comment: second you are calling another thread in run method.. which i don't understand. you can do your all the task in single run method no need to create another thread in run method

Comment: I think yours textView will update so fast that users wont be able to view the exact score of that point. 
second of all, use Synchronized so that only once counter/thread components can be used by you/user/mobile.

Comment: the second run method updates the GUI, and thanks, counter is all i need. I will also look into Synchronized. Thanks everybody for your valued input :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should use one Thread to perform the calculation. calling another thread is of no use. i am giving you brief idea how you can achieve your goal

```
class Score extends Thread {

    private boolean counter;
    private int currentscore = 0;

    public void stopThread() throws InterruptedException {
        counter = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (counter) {
            currentscore = currentscore + 1;
            //Do rest of your work  
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

in your mainactivity
when you want to start the calculation

```
  Score score = new Score();
        score.start();
```

and when you want to stop the thread e.g. call the method of thread from mainactivity use the following

```
try {
            //        your stop event
            score.stopThread();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. It was the syntax I was unaware of. This is the right answer.

Comment: @DavidPrabhu glad it helps :)

Comment: Also, the second thread uses a handler to update the GUI. Is their a better way to do this?

Comment: And for some reason, after i call the Pause method, when I call my resumeThread method (above) the timer dosent continue to count from where it left off. any ideas on why and how to do that?